# Fresh install of RHEL 6.1 - yum failing to update

Tags: linux, yum, rhel6

I'm getting some errors when trying to update some RHEL 6.1 64 bit servers with yum. I tried a fresh install of the OS and then ran yum -y upgrade and received the same errors that I was getting on my production servers.

I've tried `yum -y upgrade --skip-broken` and `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` and neither seemed to help.

I think the problem might be that we are missing a package on our satellite servers, but I'm not really sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sed for package: redhat-lsb-4.0-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sed for package: policycoreutils-2.0.83-19.8.el6_0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sed for package: groff-1.18.1.4-21.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sed for package: initscripts-9.03.23-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Skip-broken could not solve problems
Error: Package: initscripts-9.03.23-1.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
       Requires: /bin/sed
       Removing: sed-4.2.1-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
           Not found
       Updated By: sed-4.2.1-7.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-fastrack-6)
           Not found
Error: Package: redhat-lsb-4.0-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
       Requires: /bin/sed
       Removing: sed-4.2.1-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
           Not found
       Updated By: sed-4.2.1-7.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-fastrack-6)
           Not found
Error: Package: groff-1.18.1.4-21.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
       Requires: /bin/sed
       Removing: sed-4.2.1-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
           Not found
       Updated By: sed-4.2.1-7.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-fastrack-6)
           Not found
Error: Package: policycoreutils-2.0.83-19.8.el6_0.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
       Requires: /bin/sed
       Removing: sed-4.2.1-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
           Not found
       Updated By: sed-4.2.1-7.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-fastrack-6)
           Not found
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and was able to resolve it by manually updating the sed package:

```
rpm -Uvh ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/linux/scientificlinux/6.1/x86_64/updates/fastbugs/sed-4.2.1-7.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

After that installed, I was able to run `yum -y update` without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of weird, the output says:

```
Error: Package: initscripts-9.03.23-1.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
   Requires: /bin/sed
   Removing: sed-4.2.1-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201105101844.x86_64/6.1)
       Not found
   Updated By: sed-4.2.1-7.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-fastrack-6)
       Not found
```

...which means that yum wants to upgrade from sed-4.2.1-5 to sed-4.2.1-7, but it thinks that if it does so then the newer package doesn't provide /bin/sed ... so a bunch of things fail because they depend on exactly that path.

It's possible this is true, but it seems like a really weird error for Red Hat not to have caught.

In general I've never needed --skip-broken for RHEL ... so I'm a bit suspicious of if you have some weird repo. setup (ie. fastrack but nothing else).

I'd run "yum repolist" and see what it says, and drop the --skip-broken and see what that says.

Comment: yum repolist says that I have the following repositories rhel-x86_64-server-6, fastback, optional, and supplementary.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
yum search sed
yum update -y *sed package from search*
```

Make sure you have updates repo enabled in /etc/yum.repos.d/reponame.repo.